# how to dynamically add REQUIRED attribute to input tags based on output of select tag using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `select` tag with two options 'new' and 'edit'

when someone selects the 'new' option all the `input` tags in that form should be marked required and when someone selects 'edit' only a few should be marked required.

```
<select name="todo" id="todo" required> 
    <option value="">---</option>
    <option value="new">Add</option>
    <option value="edit">Edit</option>
</select>
```

Now I tried some functions but they don't seem to work

```
<script>
var todo = $('#todo option:selected').text();
if (todo == "new") {
    $('#Name').attr('required',true);
} else if (todo == "edit") {
    //code
}
</script>
```

and

```
<script>
function req() {
    var selectBox = document.getElementById('todo');
    var userInput = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
    if (userInput == 'new') {
        $('#Name').attr('required',true);
    } else if (todo == "edit") {
        //code
    }
}
</script>

where
<select name="todo" id="todo" onchange="return req();" required></select>
```

just to be sure if it works I put a `alert()` method in the if condition, but that alert is never fired.

PS. one of the input tags is

```
<input type="text" id="Name" name="Name">
```

Thank you for your time in advance...

EDIT

As pointed out by @Maximillian Laumeister in second snippet there was a typo error (which I have corrected here). (sorry for that)

Comment: Are you planning on having only this two options on your selected? If, so you may want to consider using radio buttons instead!

Comment: You need to use change event (there is no event defined in first example), also, you don't need text() property, you need val() property, and wrap your code in doc ready function: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ if you will use jQuery.

Comment: @Gacci using select instead of radio buttons is just my preference.

Comment: @nevermind thank you... :) I will keep that in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be ebough to get you going.
onchange detects whenever a different selection is made. Then based on what option is selected you perform the different instructions.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#todo').on('change', function(event){
    alert(this.value);
    if(this.value === 'edit'){
      
    }
    else if(this.value === 'new'){
      
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="todo" id="todo" required> 
    <option value="">---</option>
    <option value="new">Add</option>
    <option value="edit">Edit</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your script here you have a typo that throws a console error:

```
function req() {
    var selectBox = document.getElementById('todo');
    var userInput = selectBox.options[selectbox.selectedIndex].value;
    if (userInput == 'new') {
        $('#Name').attr('required',true);
    } else if (todo == "edit") {
        //code
    }
}
```

Where it says

```
selectBox.options[selectbox.selectedIndex].value
```

selectBox needs a capitalization like this:

```
selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value
```

It seems to be working for me with that one change.

---

Also, since you asked, your first script isn't working because it needs to be bound to run when the select changes, just like with the first one. In addition, you need to use jQuery's `val` instead of `text` to get the value of an `option` tag. Here is a working version of your second script:

```
$("#todo").change(function () {
    var todo = $('#todo option:selected').val();
    if (todo == "new") {
        $('#Name').attr('required',true);
    } else if (todo == "edit") {
        //code
    }
});
```

Comment: that works...thanks... :) but what about the first snippet? why doesn't that work?

Comment: the first code you posted here works...but the second doesn't.

Comment: @equitharn You mean to say the second code I posted here works, but the first doesn't?

Comment: @equitharn It seems like our chat link got lost (that's where I continued this discussion), so here's another link: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87116/discussion-between-equitharn-and-maximillian-laumeister

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("select").change(function(){
   if($(this).val() === "new")
       $("#Name").attr("required","required");
   });
```

You used the `option` text which is "Add" but in your if statement you compared it to the string "new". That's the reason your code didnt work as expected.

Comment: Code dumps are not useful answers. Say *what* you did, and *why*.